# Flexbox responsive row column layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following

**HTML**

```
<div>
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="center"></div>
   <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve the following layouts using **flexbox**.

**Mobile**

[image: mobile layout]

**Tablet**

[image: tablet layout]

**Desktop**

[image]

I have no problem with mobile and desktop layouts, but could not solve it for tablets.

How to force `.center` div appear after `.letf` and `.right`? Is there a way to achieve it with flexbox?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This code will achieve what you want in tablet, you can wrap it in a media query for tablet size.

The key is to set the width of left and right to 50%, center to 100% and then declare "flex-flow: row wrap;" on the container.

```
#container{
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.left{
  order: 1;
  width:50%;
  background-color: red;
}
.right{
  order: 2;
  width:50%;
  background-color: green;
}
.center{
  order: 3;
  width:100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

<div id="container">
   <div class="left">left</div>
   <div class="center">center</div>
   <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Here's a pen with a demo https://codepen.io/Washable/pen/ZXxYPJ

Comment: Nice work, you've demonstrated what I was describing and posted at the same time :)

Comment: @TidyDev You can't imagine, how much I thank you.

Answer (score 11):

With the usage of `order` and

```
@media(min-width:768px) {
  .flexbox {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
  ...
}
```

**In total**

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #565656;
  padding: 5px;
  align-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.flexbox>div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 5px;
}

.flexbox>.left {
  background-color: #D30058;
}

.flexbox>.center {
  background-color: #36ABE1;
}

.flexbox>.right {
  background-color: #23B776;
}

@media(min-width:576px) {
  .flexbox {
    flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
  .flexbox>.left {
    order: 1;
    flex: 0.5;
  }
  .flexbox>.right {
    order: 2;
    flex: 0.5;
  }
  .flexbox>.center {
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  .flexbox {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
  }
  .flexbox>div {
    width: 33.33% !important;
  }
  .flexbox>.left {
    order: 1;
  }
  .flexbox>.center {
    order: 2;
  }
  .flexbox>.right {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="center">center</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a flexbox property called `order` that could be useful here since you want the center div to come last: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order

There are probably other solutions too, but this is something you should know about :) Hint: you can use media queries to change the order as desired.

See also `flex-flow: row wrap;`